# ecdsa signing key format

Tags: python, bitcoin

I am trying to create a public/private key pair using python.

I have created a private key using the following method:

```
private_key = ''.join(['%x' % random.randrange(16) for x in range(0, 64)])
```

using this private key I have attempted to use a ecdsa graph to generate to corresponding public key

```
def privateKeyToPublicKey(s):
    sk = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(s, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
    vk = sk.verifying_key
    return ('\04' + sk.verifying_key.to_string())
```

I have not been able to create the signing key (sk) due to a formatting error where my string is in the wrong format. But I am not sure how/what format the string s should be for SigningKey to work.

I get the following error when running the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "address.py", line 23, in <module>
    privateKeyToPublicKey(private_key)
  File "address.py", line 20, in privateKeyToPublicKey
    sk = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(s, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ecdsa/keys.py", line 
149, in from_string
    assert len(string) == curve.baselen, (len(string), curve.baselen)
AssertionError: (64, 32)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more complete code sample for clarity about the answer. Python3.

```
    from ecdsa import SigningKey, SECP256k1
    import sha3, random, binascii

    private_key = ''.join(['%x' % random.randrange(16) for x in range(0, 64)])
    private_key = bytes(private_key, 'utf-8')
    private_key = binascii.unhexlify(private_key)
    priv = SigningKey.from_string(private_key, curve=SECP256k1)
    pub = priv.get_verifying_key().to_string()
    keccak = sha3.keccak_256()
    keccak.update(pub)
    address = keccak.hexdigest()[24:]
    print(address, priv.to_string().hex())
```

Comment: Hi could you please explain the role of the:
keccak = sha3.keccak_256()
    keccak.update(pub)
    address = keccak.hexdigest()[24:]

Answer (score 0):

I have realised my error, the input must be in bytes, the private key in hex format. In python2 you may use:

```
private_key.decode('hex')
```

or you may use

```
binascii.unhexlify
```

in python3